# How to write the filter condition in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have some code logic which is written in javascript. I am new to ruby and I would like to write the same logic in Ruby. Here is the logic

```
var accountsToBlock = allExceedersArray.filter(accountId => !blockedExceedersArray.includes(accountId));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
accounts_to_block = all_exceeders_array.select do |account_id| 
  !blocked_exceeders_array.include?(account_id) 
end
```

Comment: It is not returning expected output

Comment: provide more information then. and examples of the two arrays. because this is the exact translation of your code to ruby

Comment: The requirement is like we need to block the accounts who are exceeded the free limit., So There are 2 sets of account Id's. One is accounts which are **all_exceeders** and another set is already blocked. Now I have those 2 sets of accounts list. I need to subtract second set from first set.

Comment: I am getting the error for the code you provided. Can you please check once **NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for 16:Integer**

Comment: it seems `blocked_exceeders_array` is an integer, not an array as we expect :) check that please

Answer (score 0):

ruby also has a `filter` method, but I would look at the ruby `reject` [method](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/reject), as it's more readable to say

```
all_exceeders.reject { |account_id| blocked_exceeders.include?(account_id) }
```

than

```
all_exceeders.filter { |account_id| !blocked_exceeders.include?(account_id) }
```